# "It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long" while running test in experitest

Tags: appium, appium-android, seetest, experitest

I am trying to run my test in an android mobile in a cloud platform `cloud.seetest.io` by installing appium studio plugin in eclipse so that test can be run directly from eclipse IDE itself.

It is always giving the error as

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible

```
@BeforeMethod
    @Parameters("deviceQuery")
    public void setUp(@Optional("@os='android'") String deviceQuery)throws Exception{

    init(deviceQuery);
        // Init application / device capabilities
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "cloud:xxxxxxxx/.xxxx");
    dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "xxxxx");
    dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, ".xxxxxx");
    dc.setCapability(SeeTestCapabilityType.DEVICE_QUERY, deviceQuery);
    dc.setCapability(SeeTestCapabilityType.TEST_NAME, "AndroidDemoTest");
    dc.setCapability("appVersion", "1.0.10516");
    dc.setCapability("testName", "AndroidDemoTest");
    driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(getProperty("url",cloudProperties) + "/wd/hub"), dc);

    }
```

Comment: check your appium server log or add full appium server log in above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when the driver is unable to get initiated. While connecting to experitest, these could have been the problems which give this error:

1. Licence of Experitest. If the licence is for one device/session at a time, one cannot attempt to create another session.
2. Desired Capabilities. Make sure that the device with the device id you mentioned in the code is available in the seetest cloud. Best practice is to first block the device and then copy the UDID to code.

In fact, there can be many reasons which could lead to no driver getting created. The actual reason behind this error is mentioned down there itself in the stack trace. Go down the stack trace and you will find the actual reason.

In my case it was the second one that happened.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your [Appium client library](https://github.com/appium/java-client) version is not supported, as per [Set Appium Java Client](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java) chapter:

> You could make use of the Appium Java Client by adding a dependency to your Maven and Gradle projects
>
> Please make sure you replace  with the appropriate version:
>
> - 4.1.2
> - 5.0.4
> - 6.1.0
> - 7.0.0
>
> **It is recommended to use the public maven repo before the code export.**

So inspect your dependency management file and make sure to update the [io.appium.java-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client) dependency to one of the supported versions.

Answer (score 0):

Experitest's client libraries might be missing. Try adding `compile 'com.experitest:repo:+'` in your build.gradle. This would download the latest client libraries. [This](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Appium+Studio+for+Eclipse+-+Project+Configuration) document might help you in creating a sample project with Appium Studio plugin

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1st**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "xyz");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Platform.ANDROID);
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.hp.HPSupportAssistant");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.hp.HPSupportAssistant.MainActivity");
 capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 6000);    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS,true);
//desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```

**Here  comment below line and then run it will work** 
desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);

**solution 2nd 
Or keep above line in desired capabilities but before that do
run 3 cmd on cmd promt**

```
adb shell pm list packages -f > D://t.txt
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test

desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```